# reset v-text-field to empty text without triggering a "must not be empty"-rule

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuetify.js

I have a basic input text field and want to reset it after submitting. When resetting it I currently update its v-model to an empty string. Unfortunately this triggers my input rules and renders an error message.

Code example:

```
<div id="app">
    <v-app>
        <v-text-field v-model="text" :rules="[value => !!value || 'Required']"></v-text-field>
        <v-btn @click="text = ''">submit and reset</v-btn>
    </v-app>
</div>

new Vue({
    el: '#app',
    vuetify: new Vuetify(),
    data() {
        return {
            text: ""
        };
    }
})
```

Is there a way I can empty the field without triggering the rule? I mean it behaves correctly and I would expect that, but when I click on the button I want to reset the field to its initial state.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you put it within a form you can call `form.reset()`

```
<v-form
    ref="form"
    >
     <v-text-field v-model="text" :rules="[value => !!value || 'Required']"></v-text-field>
     <v-btn @click="submit">submit and reset</v-btn>
</v-form>
```

```
methods : {
  submit () {
     this.$refs.form.reset()
  }
}
```

the example codepen used in the docs: https://codepen.io/ellisdod/pen/jOPpzOO

https://vuetifyjs.com/en/components/forms/

Comment: Thanks. This has bothered me for 3 days.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to reset form validation only, but not form inputs, you better call `this.$refs.form.resetValidation()` . Because *.reset()* method will clear all inputs (all values will be =**null**) and reset their validation errors (according to [Vuetify docs](https://vuetifyjs.com/en/components/forms/#validation-with-submit-26-clear)).